# pandas StataWriter: Writing an iterator for large queries; .dta file corrupt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, stata

I'm trying to subclass the pandas `StataWriter` to allow passing a SQL query with `chunksize` to avoid running out of memory on very large result sets. I've gotten most of the way there, but am getting an error when I try to open up the file that is written by pandas in STATA: `.dta file corrupt: The marker </data> was not found in the file where it was expected to be. This means that the file was written incorrectly or that the file has subsequently become damaged.`

From what I can tell in my code, it should be working; the `self._update_map("data")` is properly update the location of the tag. Here are the contents of `self._map`:

```py
{'stata_data': 0, 'map': 158, 'variable_types': 281, 'varnames': 326, 'sortlist': 1121, 'formats': 1156, 'value_label_names': 1517, 'variable_labels': 2330, 'characteristics': 4291, 'data': 4326, 'strls': 52339, 'value_labels': 52354, 'stata_data_close': 52383, 'end-of-file': 52395}
```

This `end-of-file` entry matches the byte-size of the file (52,395 == 52,395):

```bash
-rw------- 1 tallen wrds 52395 Nov  8 08:34 test.dta
```

Here's the code I've come up with. What am I missing to properly position the end `</data>` tag?

```py
from collections.abc import Hashable, Sequence
from datetime import datetime

from pandas import read_sql_query
from pandas._typing import (
    CompressionOptions,
    DtypeArg,
    FilePath,
    StorageOptions,
    WriteBuffer,
)
from pandas.io.stata import StataWriterUTF8
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Connection


class SQLStataWriter(StataWriterUTF8):
    """
    Writes a STATA binary file without using an eager dataframe, avoiding loading the
    entire result into memory.

    Only supports writing modern STATA 15 (118) and 16 (119) .dta files since they are
    the only versions to support UTF-8.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        fname: FilePath | WriteBuffer[bytes],
        sql: str = None,
        engine: Connection = None,
        chunksize: int = 10000,
        dtype: DtypeArg | None = ...,
        convert_dates: dict[Hashable, str] | None = None,
        write_index: bool = True,
        byteorder: str | None = None,
        time_stamp: datetime | None = None,
        data_label: str | None = None,
        variable_labels: dict[Hashable, str] | None = None,
        convert_strl: Sequence[Hashable] | None = None,
        version: int | None = None,
        compression: CompressionOptions = "infer",
        storage_options: StorageOptions | None = None,
        *,
        value_labels: dict[Hashable, dict[float, str]] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        # Bind the additional variables to self
        self.sql = text(sql)
        self.engine = engine
        self.chunksize = chunksize
        self.dtype = dtype

        # Create the dataframe for init by pulling the first row only
        for data in read_sql_query(
            self.sql,
            self.engine,
            chunksize=1,
            dtype=self.dtype,
        ):
            break

        super().__init__(
            fname,
            data,
            convert_dates,
            write_index,
            byteorder=byteorder,
            time_stamp=time_stamp,
            data_label=data_label,
            variable_labels=variable_labels,
            convert_strl=convert_strl,
            version=version,
            compression=compression,
            storage_options=storage_options,
            value_labels=value_labels,
        )

    def _prepare_data(self):
        """
        This will be called within _write_data in the loop instead.
        """
        return None

    def _write_data(self, records) -> None:
        """
        Override this to loop over records in chunksize.
        """
        self._update_map("data")
        self._write_bytes(b"<data>")

        # Instead of eagerly loading the entire dataframe, do it in chunks.
        for self.data in read_sql_query(
            self.sql,
            self.engine,
            chunksize=self.chunksize,
            dtype=self.dtype,
        ):
            # Insert an index column or values expected will be off by one. Be
            # sure to use len(self.data) in case the last chunk is fewer rows
            # than the chunksize.
            self.data.insert(0, "index", list(range(0, len(self.data))))

            # Call the parent function to prepare rows for this chunk only.
            records = super()._prepare_data()
            # Write the records to the file
            self._write_bytes(records.tobytes())

        self._write_bytes(b"</data>")
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found that the `self._map` dict has different values when using the `chunksize` writer versus the original:

*With chunksize, `strls` is 13,939 (which doesn't work):*

```py
{'stata_data': 0, 'map': 158, 'variable_types': 281, 'varnames': 326, 'sortlist': 1121, 'formats': 1156, 'value_label_names': 1517, 'variable_labels': 2330, 'characteristics': 4291, 'data': 4326, 'strls': 13939, 'value_labels': 13954, 'stata_data_close': 13983, 'end-of-file': 13995}
```

*Without chunksize, `strls` is 13,139 (which works):*

```py
{'stata_data': 0, 'map': 158, 'variable_types': 281, 'varnames': 326, 'sortlist': 1121, 'formats': 1156, 'value_label_names': 1517, 'variable_labels': 2330, 'characteristics': 4291, 'data': 4326, 'strls': 13139, 'value_labels': 13154, 'stata_data_close': 13183, 'end-of-file': 13195}
```

It appears that the loop writing the bytes may be padding the beginning or end:

- It seems to be adding four bytes per row.
- When I do 200 rows, the difference is 800 bytes.
- When I do 1000 rows, the different is 4000 bytes.

I'm fairly certain this is because of the "index row" I'm adding to keep the arrays storing column types and keys from being off-by-one adding a 4-byte integer to each row. Investigating further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving deep into the internals of `pandas` to try to make this work, I decided to move in another direction.

I ended up having PostgreSQL output a CSV file, [then using the `readstat` C library's CSV to STATA conversion](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat/#command-line-usage-with-csv-input). This library keeps memory usage low by iterating over the CSV, rather than eagerly loading the entire result into memory.

Some tips:

- Be sure `libcsv`'s dev package is installed. On Ubuntu, that means `libcsv-dev`, on CentOS and friends, that's `libcsv-devel`.
- You can tell if you have successfully compiled with `libcsv` by running the `readstat` command. If you have, it will include this text:

```
Convert a CSV file with column metadata stored in a separate JSON file (see extract_metadata):

     bin/readstat input.csv metadata.json output.(dta|por|sav|sas7bdat|xpt|zsav|csv)
```

- If you don't see the preceding text, the `configure` command couldn't find `libcsv`'s dev headers.
- The JSON format can be a little tricky. All columns must be `STRING` or `NUMERIC`, with an optional format passed for things like `DATE` or `DATE_TIME`. Here's one with a `NUMERIC`, `DATE`, and `STRING` that worked:

```json
{
    "type": "STATA",
    "variables": [
        {
            "type": "STRING",
            "name": "string_column",
            "label": "String Column",
            "missing": {"type": "DISCRETE","values": [""]}
        },
        {
            "type": "NUMERIC",
            "name": "date_column",
            "label": "Date Column",
            "format": "DATE"
        },
        {
            "type": "NUMERIC",
            "name": "numeric_column",
            "label": "Numeric Columns",
            "format": "UNSPECIFIED"
        }
    ]
}
```